# Trying To Add Window Crashing The Application

Tags: android

I am making an application.In application i am having tabs on bottom. First tab showing two button. ON click of button i want to open barcode scanner. And one more thing First time i was not creating ActivityGroups It was running fine for me. But after creating ActivityGroup class on click of buton application is crashing and giving me following error.

```
   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1774): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable  to   add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@44f557d8 is  not valid; is your activity running?
```

Comment: post your code that how you are adding button.

Comment: This error means that you are trying to add some View to an activity that has already finished.

Answer (score 0):

you passed context of any activity to somewhere , then activity is finished(by yourself or by Android) now you are trying to use this context .

usually people do this for using method/variable of an activity outside it . never do this , 
keep activity context inside this activity always .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the `Context` of your `Activity` and you should use actually the `Context` of your `ActivityGroup`. There are no mentions of this in any docs that I know of, but I have encountered this and this is most likely your problem too.
You could pass the context of your `ActivityGroup` to your `Activity` or use `getParent()` in your `Activity` to get the right `Context`.

Also I would recommend using `Fragments` since `ActivityGroup` is deprecated and is producing a lot of problems, just like the one that you have encountered.